# Steps On Posting Ads through Longtail JW Player

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

Hi I downloaded the **JW Player** and started to work with it and I've run it with **Apache2** and played a simple video on it.

Now my question is how to perform the [AdSolution](http://www.longtailvideo.com/adsolution/demos/)
I need to post the Ads on it and need to demonstrate pre-roll,overlay and post-roll.I tried the link of [Longtail](http://www.longtailvideo.com/adsolution/demos/).It is asking me to [signup](https://dashboard.longtailvideo.com/signup.aspx).I dont have the site URL and the video site URL.Is there any possible way to perform it with out signing it up.Or any free scripts links to start working with it.It would be great if any tutorials are available for the easy usage of the **longtail JW player** *to be used for the Ads Demonstration*.***Any Blogs or any site giving the simple steps for the Ads demonstration with codes and scripts on JW Player are welcome.***

> Thanks,Gladnick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdSolution is really simple. You just add a few lines of code to the player code and the AdSolution is included as a Plugin. When you sign up you will get your own ad ID code, then you can go to the "Dashboard" and enable or disable the different ad types (preroll, overlay,etc). This is the complete modification to your code:

```
    'plugins': {
    'ltas': {
    'cc': 'yourID'";
       } 
     }
```

If you want to see a demo of all this sort of thing working, sign up for blip.Tv and put some movies on there and enable ads. It will take a few days for the ads to run, but they have preroll, postroll, and overlay. I don't use blip anymove because i found them extremely unreliable and technically challenged.

Comment: It would be great if there is a way with out signing as it asks for a site and we dont have it.